# Creating postgres database in external hard disc

Tags: postgresql

I want to create my postgres database in an external hard disc because the disc it's installed in, doesn't have enough space.

I have edited the `postgresql.conf` file following way

```
data_directory = '/media/afnan/Important/postgres_db'
```

After I restart the postgres server with

```
sudo systemctl restart postgresql
```

and run `pg_lsclusters`, the postgres cluster status remains down.

```
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner Data directory                  Log file
13  main    5432 down   afnan /media/afnan/Important/postgres /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-13-main.log
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you initialise the new data directory or move the contents of the old one over? There's not much point in trying to connect to the DB when it says "status = down". Check the logs to see why it is down

Comment: I just created a new directory in my external hard disc and updated the `postgresql.conf` file

Comment: Read up on `initdb` or move the previous directory structure over. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/app-initdb.html. Oh, and needless to say if your external disk ever has problems while postgresql is doing anything you'll have problems, so keep regular backups.

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy/move the data from the old location to the new location.  Changing postgresql.conf only tells it to look in a different place for the data. The data still needs to be in that new place when it does look for it--you need to make that happen yourself.